# JS/jQuery AJAX (odd and even conditional layouts) with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple PHP loop that is returning a different layout if the `$count` is odd or even (image on left, text on right if odd and text on left, image on right if even).

I've then set this up with [Waypoints Infinite Scroll](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/) which is essentially an AJAX loading of content from the next page and therefore, as the `$count` is server side but the AJAX is client side, it breaks the count and therefore every item that is loaded in the `else` even layout.

Is there a way to do this to it keeps the `$count` and would return correctly?

```
<?php $count = 0; foreach ($news as $article) : ?>
    <?php if ($count % 2 != 0) : // Odd ?>
        // Odd layout
    <?php else : // Even ?>
        // Even layout
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: store a variable in the js and send it with each request to continue the counter, use sessions, create simple math with the limit,offset to see the counter in the php. I think this question is too broad.

Comment: @VasilShaddix What is too broad about it? It's pretty specific...

Comment: It's not specific, I told you some ways you can achieve this, there are plenty more.

Comment: @VasilShaddix Just because there's more than one way to achieve it doesn't mean the question isn't specific.

Comment: what is so specific about this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use session or cookie for this

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $_SESSION['count'] = 0; foreach ($news as $article) : ?>
    <?php if ($_SESSION['count'] % 2 != 0) : // Odd ?>
        // Odd layout
    <?php else : // Even ?>
        // Even layout
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $_SESSION['count']++; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why session or cookie ?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for this. I'll give this a go.